# How to return ajax value in success from multiple user defined funtion?

Tags: ajax

I may be wrong with the title I dont how how to express it..

I dont know whether its a duplicate one ,if yes pls dont neglect since i'm stuck with this one.

what i need?

I have an ajax function call,using onchange event from 3 select boxes

The values will be passed to the next page ajax1.php for execution and is returned back based on class name.

Is it possible ,how can i retrieve the value since all three function call are on same funnction

```
<select name="start" onchange="ajaxcall('start',this.value)">
   <option value="1">kerala </option>
</select>
<td class="hc"></td>
<select name="hotel" onchange="ajaxcall('hotel',this.value)">
   <option value="1">Taj </option>
</select>
<td class="hc1"></td>
<select name="room" onchange="ajaxcall('room',this.value)">
   <option value="1">single_bed </option>
</select>
<td class="hc2"></td>
```

My ajax function will be:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function ajaxcall(value1,type){
   var parameters = 'hotel_category='+type;
   var argUrl = 'ajax_hotels.php';
    $.ajax({
        url: argUrl,
        type: 'POST',
        data: parameters,
        success: function (str) {
        $(".hc1").html(str);    //here i'm confused hw to give the class name commonly so that the values can be returned based on the function call.
        //alert(parameters);                
        }

                });
            }
```

I write the code and got stuck at the succcess:function() place since i dont know how to direct the value to the respective

I didnt tried executing it.

Thanks in advance guys.......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your html code will look like

```
<select name="start" onchange="ajaxcall('hc',this.value)">
   <option value="1">kerala </option>
</select>
<td class="hc"></td>
<select name="hotel" onchange="ajaxcall('hc1',this.value)">
   <option value="1">Taj </option>
</select>
<td class="hc1"></td>
<select name="room" onchange="ajaxcall('hc2',this.value)">
   <option value="1">single_bed </option>
</select>
<td class="hc2"></td>
```

And you ajax success function will contain,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function ajaxcall(value1,type){
   var element = document.getElementById(type);
   var val = element.options[element.selectedIndex].value;
   var parameters = {"hotel_category" : type, "value1" : val};
   var argUrl = 'ajax_hotels.php';
    $.ajax({
        url: argUrl,
        type: 'POST',
        data: parameters,
        success: function (str) {
        $("."+value1).html(str);            
        }
       });
   }
</script>
```

Comment: Just replace $(".hc1").html(str); with the above line

Comment: i will be having the code of ajax.php page like this:....................................<?php $s=$_POST['hotel_category'];$t=$_POST['valule1'];if($t=='hotel'{statement1}else if($t=='start'){statement 2}else if($t=='room'){statement3}......in this case how can i retrieve the val in sccess functon

Comment: Let me know whether it worked? Find the example http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/beginners-guide-to-ajax-development-with-php

Comment: i tried this code but not working...i cant understand whats  tag-load ect...http://www.codedisqus.com/0ySVgXWUgX/jquery-load-304-notmodified.html